# Simplest way to validate depending properties of @RequestBody with a custom validator

Tags: spring-boot, customvalidator

I got an endpoint looking like this:

```
@PostMapping(produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
Event createEvent (@RequestBody(required = true) @Valid EventRequestBody eventRequestBody) {
.....
}
```

My EventRequestBody looks like this:

```
class EventRequestBody {
    @NotNull
    Long start //represents timestamp
    @NotNull
    Long end //represents timestamp
}
```

I already told spring boot that both properties are mandatory. But i also want spring boot to check that the start property has to be smaller than the end property. There are some threads out there to do this with custom validation. But all of them are confusing me and i really dont know which way is the most simple and properly working way.

Any suggestions?

Comment: YOu haven't told Spring Boot anything, you configured it for validation. Write a class validator which validates the fields.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to do it with `ConstraintValidator`. You should to do something like this:
Declare a custom annotation:

```
@Documented
@Constraint(validatedBy = ValidatorValuesImpl.class)
@Target({TYPE})
@Retention(RUNTIME)
public @interface ValidatorValues {

  String message() default "End before start";

  Class[] groups() default {};

  Class[] payload() default {};
}
```

Also a implementation of this annotation

```
public class ValidatorValuesImpl implements ConstraintValidator<ValidatorValues, EventRequestBody> {


  @Override
  public void initialize(ValidatorValues constraintAnnotation) {
    ConstraintValidator.super.initialize(constraintAnnotation);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean isValid(EventRequestBody value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
    return value.getEnd().compareTo(value.getStart()) > 0;
  }
}
```

On your `EventRequestBody` class add next one annotation `@ValidatorValues`

The final result will look:

```
@ValidatorValues
class EventRequestBody {
    @NotNull
    Long start //represents timestamp
    @NotNull
    Long end //represents timestamp
}
```

And on *controller/service layer it depends on the situation.* you will invoke next one method:

```
  private final Validator validator;
    ...
  @PostMapping(produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
  Event createEvent (@RequestBody(required = true) @Valid EventRequestBody eventRequestBody) {
    Set<ConstraintViolation<EventRequestBody>> validate = validator.validate(eventRequestBody);
      ...

  }
```

For more details check [Validation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/core/validation/beanvalidation.html)

Comment: compared to grails (which is based on spring boot) with its custom validator closure in classes which implement Validateable, the spring boot way is very laborious. but well, this is the way to got. thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can provide an extra method for @AssertTrue like below. that method will be called automatically and checks your condition.

```java
@Getter
@Setter
public class EventRequestBody {
    private Long startTime;
    private Long endTime;

    // Getters and setters

    @AssertTrue(message = "startTime must be before endTime")
    private boolean isValidTimeRange() {
        return endTime.compareTo(startTime) > 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use an if statement to check if the start property is smaller than the end property and it it's true you do whatever treatment you want else you just return an error message but in this scenario you will have to change the return type to ResponseEntity

Comment: There is nothing preventing the user from writing a class validator to validate the fields.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).