# Custom validation in elements of a list of a rest request

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, javax-validation

I have a spring rest service that receives a list of elements, like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/foobar", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
public ... foobar(
        @Valid @RequestBody(required = true) List<Exp> listDto) {
```

I created an annotation @MyConstraint,

```
@Constraint(validatedBy = MyValidator.class)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface MyConstraint{

    String message() default "differents in list";

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};

}
```

and

```
public class MyValidator
    implements ConstraintValidator<MyConstraint, List<Exp>> {

@Override
public boolean isValid(List<Exp> values, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {

    return values.stream() //
                    .map(Exp::getExpedientes) //
                    .map(G::getIdArea) //
                    .distinct() //
                    .count() != 1;// more than one

    }

@Override
public void initialize(MyConstraint constraintAnnotation) {
    ConstraintValidator.super.initialize(constraintAnnotation);
    }

}

@MyConstraint
public class Exp {
    private List<G> expedientes;
}   

public class G  {
    private Integer idArea;
}
```

but when I make a request to my web service, the validation is not being executed, even setting a *return false;*, the request is received, am I missing something to indicate the execution of the validation?

Comment: I wrote an answer about custom validator, [custom validator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76993688/simplest-way-to-validate-depending-properties-of-requestbody-with-a-custom-vali/76994067#76994067), can you check ? Because from first view i saw 2 escapes in your current implementation, also if it helped you, don't forget to upvote that answer(approved) one

Comment: @AndreiLisa hi! I checked your code, added the missing line in the initialize, and change the MyValidator annotation in the Exp class, with the same result, the request is being processed, in your example the validation is executed explicitly in the first method's line, isn't there a way to make that execution implicit by the @Valid?

Comment: What version of spring boot are you using ?

Answer (score 0):

Just annotating `@Valid` on the method argument is not enough . You also have to annotate  `@Validated` at the controller class level in order to enable the  method validation. Do you miss it ? Something like the following :

```java
@RestController
@Validated
public class FooController {
  
  @RequestMapping(value = "/foobar", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
  public ... foobar(@Valid @RequestBody(required = true) List<Exp> listDto) {


  }
}
```

It is mentioned at [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/core/validation/beanvalidation.html#validation-beanvalidation-spring-method) :

> To be eligible for Spring-driven method validation, **all target classes need to be annotated with Spring’s @Validated annotation**, which can optionally also declare the validation groups to use.

Comment: I am agree with you in the case if version of spring-boot is < 3.x. From spring-boot > 3.x `@Validated` annotation is not necessary.

Comment: really ? which version ? any release notes mention this ? just try spring-boot3 .0.2  still need to add @Validated

Comment: '3.1.1' this is the version as i said the `@Validated` is not necessary.

Comment: good to know. but i just try even up to 3.1.3 and `@Validated` is still required. do i miss something ?

Comment: Sorry i did some confuses but how i understood from [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/6.1/web/webmvc/mvc-controller/ann-validation.html#:~:text=Spring%20MVC%20has%20built%2Din,support%20works%20on%20two%20levels.) it is so, also some remarks it is from spring framework 6.1. My bad